# Providing transparency on or providing transparency of?

Tags: grammaticality

I am wondering about the wording of this sentence: *Empowering solid decisions by providing transparency of the system landscape and IT processes.*

I'd like to ask if "on" can be used in this context as opposed to "of" and which variant sounds better/is more correct. And what about using "... making transparent the system landscape ..." versus "... providing transparency of/on the system landscape...", which one of these alternatives is better? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: I don't like either of your prepositions. How about: *"providing transparency in"*, *"providing transparency for"*, or *"giving transparency to"*?

Comment: Or "Empowering solid decisions by making the system landscape and IT processes more transparent."

Comment: @Peter Shor: I think that your third suggestion fits very well, thank you!

Comment: @tinyd: That's a good suggestion but I feel that by saying "more transparent" there is an implication that we aren't providing anywhere near full transparency on those topics.

Comment: @Haris - that's a fair point. You could change it to "Empowering solid decisions by making the system landscape and IT processes fully transparent", but Peter's choices are very applicable. As a small note, I would prefer "enabling" to "empowering" in this context, but I'm not sure why :)

Comment: If transparency is indeed something that you can provide in connection with "the system landscape and IT processes," I recommend using "with regard to" in place of "of" or "on": "Empowering solid decisions by providing transparency with regard to the system landscape and IT processes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason the prepositions sound strange is because of "providing". Try using "increasing":

> Empowering solid decisions by increasing the transparency of the system landscape and IT processes.

Synonyms of "increasing" would also work..

Answer (score 0):

How about "into"?

> Empowering solid decisions by providing transparency into the system
>   landscape and IT processes.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a core marketing blurb, I would be more direct and succinct while using a keyword that highlights the novel benefit of your service:

Empowering solid decisions by **introducing** transparency **to** the system landscape and IT processes